# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration

Tags: java, hibernate, tomcat, classnotfoundexception

I'm building a rest api using jersey, and it needs to communicate with a mysql database. Decided to use Hibernate, but am getting this exception on line 51, the line where I initialize the SessionFactory object. Here it is:

```
51    SessionFactory sessionFactory = new Configuration()
52                  .configure()
53                  .buildSessionFactory();
```

Here is the error:

```
Apr 28, 2016 1:05:03 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [org.lockedout.pollinator.api.MyApp] in context with path [/resources] threw exception [org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/cfg/Configuration] with root cause
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1720)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1571)
    at org.lockedout.pollinator.api.PollsResource.createNewPoll(PollsResource.java:51)
```

Any insights into what could be causing the error?

Comment: have you added `Hibernate-Core` jars to your `lib` or `pom.xml`

Comment: Cause: _Hibernate libraries are not available to Tomcat._

Comment: @Mihir I'm a noob. Can you elaborate on what you mean by "hibernate libraries are not available to Tomcat," and what that means for me?

Comment: Yes Please add `hibernate-Core` Jars to your `lib` folder. If you are using maven then you can add dependency to the `pom.xml`.

Comment: import the jars into the _WEB-INF/lib_ folder of your application.

Comment: @VikrantKashyap yes, and i checked if it contained org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration; and it does

Comment: @khakis you need the hibernate libraries in the lib folder inside WEB_INF of the war. As these libraries are required at run time for your application to run.

Comment: are you using maven for build ?

Comment: @praveen yes I'm using maven. and also, do i need to type @<username> everytime i want to get someone's attention in the comments section?

Comment: yes that way the other user gets notified just like i got notified when u used @praveen

Comment: @praveen got it. so, i don't get it. i need to have two separate libraries in for my project: one for coding and one for run time?

Comment: You are using _maven_.So Plz check in _pom.xml_ , _hibernate-core_ dependency is there or not? Otherwise post _pom.xml_ to your question.

Comment: @Khakis you need jars available at both compile time (for compiling your source code) and runtime (for tomcat to run the application)

Comment: @praveen i feel like they would be one in the same i.e. any code you need for compiling would also be needed during runtime. regardless, i added the hibernate library myself without using maven, and so i needed to add the dependency to the pom file. so it's fixed, but now I have another error -_-

Comment: @Khakis tomact has its own lib folder at $CATALINA_HOME/lib and These resources are visible to all applications and to Tomcat. but there are some libraries that are not present in $CATALINA_HOME/lib and thus you need to add them in WEB-INF/lib.

Comment: Class loaders are created for each deployed Context, which load all classes and JAR files contained in each web application's WEB-INF/classes and WEB-INF/lib, respectively and in that order. These resources are only visible to the web application that loads them.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the maven war plugin to include the jars required at runtime

```
<build>
<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.6</version>
    <configuration>
      <packagingIncludes>WEB-INF/lib/hibernate-core*.jar,WEB-INF/lib/someOther*.jar</packagingIncludes>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
</plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: just copy and paste this to pom.xml?

Comment: yes just replace the {jar names} with the artifact-id or jar names that need to be added to /WEB-INF/lib.

Comment: how is this better than copy and pasting all the jars to the WEB-INF/lib folder

Comment: This is better because using the war plugin you would have automated the manually copying jars and generating a war task.

Comment: were you able to fix the issue ?

Comment: i was. the error was no longer popping up but then a 404 error was. then i did something, i'm not sure what, and all my maven dependencies disappeared. not sure how to get them back because now when i search for them, nothing comes up

Comment: try doing a mvn clean install from command prompt and deploy the artifact.

Comment: there's a lot i have to understand before i start constructing this rest api. i read docs for jersey or any other framework, and i can't understand what's being said. i'm in the process of writing an android app, and everything was going well until i decided to work on the back end, now everything is going to shit. i get the database portion, i get the app portion, but this middleware portion is kicking my ass. i got a lot more work to do until i can even begin to start creating this rest api

Comment: @khakis check out this link for learning resource its free and its amazing Developing REST APIs with JAX-RS - Java Brains https://javabrains.io/courses/javaee_jaxrs

Comment: see, like when you say try doing a mvn clean install, i have no idea what that means or how to do it; i never installed maven. it just came with eclipse. and deploy the artifact just sounds like craziness to me, like something out of indiana jones

Comment: lol i watched both of those videos. he's good. and the api was working until i started to get the 404 error, and then all my dependencies disappeared. the problem is that when nothing goes wrong, i know what i need to do, but when something does go wrong and it's not explicitly answered on the internet, i have no idea what to do but read the docs or learn more about the underlying software; and the docs either seem like gibrish, or any tutorials on the software are too broad

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110472/discussion-between-praveen-and-khakis).